# php add action to form tag if not exists

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have the following form tag

```
$content = '<form action="link.php" method="post" class="form-inputs">';
$content1 = '<form method="post" class="form-inputs">';
```

so using my regex code :

```
preg_replace("~<form\s(.|\n)*?>~i",'<form action="linkafterreplace.php" method="post">', $content);
```

When I use this code for both $content and $content1 this is what I get:

```
<form action="linkafterreplace.php" method="post">
```

and the problem is my code can't get class attributes or id attributes . 
what I want is :

```
<form action="linkafterreplace.php" method="post" class="form-inputs">
```

ps : I'm replacing many urls so every url has its own class attribute so it might not be form-inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is currently grabbing the entire form tag and replacing it with the

```
<form action="linkafterreplace.php" method="post">
```

The best way to fix this is to just check for the existence of

```
<form
```

and replace it with

```
<form action="linkafterreplace.php" method="post"
```

The call you need for that is (I haven't tested it as I'm on a computer without PHP):

```
preg_replace("~<form~i",'<form action="linkafterreplace.php" method="post"', $content);
```

Hope that makes sense...

---

EDIT:

Because of the comments, I'm modifying my answer slightly.  Again, I don't have a computer with PHP so the syntax may be slightly off.

The easiest way is to check if the form tag has an action element is to use preg_match, like so:

```
if (preg_match("~action=~i")) {    // Check to see if you find "action="
    preg_replace("~action=\".*\"~i", "action='linkafterreplace.php'", $content); // IFF so, replace it using regex.
} else {
    preg_replace("~<form~i",'<form action="linkafterreplace.php"', $content); // Otherwise add it it.
}
```

I am simply using regex to check for the existance of the "action=" inside of the form element.  If so, I use a regex replace to put in the new file name.  Otherwise, I use regex to add to the beginning like in my original answer.

Hope that works better for you!

Comment: wtf , are you kidding me? it really worked ...

Comment: wtf was the magic you did bro! thanks alot

Comment: can you explan to me why it happened because the code you gave me I thought it will make the url look like this

Comment: <form action="linkafterreplace.php" method="post" action="link.php" method="post" class="form-inputs">

Comment: because you used only ~<form~i so only <form will be replaced with <form action="linkafterreplace.php" method="post"

Comment: can you explain to me please ? :D

Comment: I'll try to make it a little more visual..

The regex takes the "<form" and chops it off, leaving any class attributes you specify.  Then it replaces it with the value you've asked for.

The problem is this code is dumb enough that it can't replace any preexisting action elements.  In order to do that, you'd need multiple regex replaces.

Comment: what do you mean by it can't replace any preexisting action elements ? can you give me an example plz

Comment: but your code isn't smart xD

Comment: if there ACTION = '' it won't replace it

Comment: That's exactly what I meant :)  I'm about to change my answer

Comment: @mus Are you assuming all form elements have an action?  or does your code need to be able to add an action if it doesn't have one?

Comment: yes add an action if it doesn't have too

Comment: and if action is like this action='' or AcTion =    '' or ACTION =   ""

Comment: I know we have to use case insensitive

Comment: and \s for espaces but I couldnt make it work

Comment: Thanks guys, this was a time saver for me